# Is there any ferry to the south of Thailand from Vietnam or Cambodia?

Tags: thailand, ferries, southeast-asia, vietnam, cambodia

I would like to go to the south of Thailand (anywhere south of Bangkok) from Cambodia or Vietnam. I have some old information (2007) about a ferry between Sihanoukville and Chanthaburi ([in Spanish](http://clubtrotamundos.blogspot.com.es/2007/11/un-nuevo-ferry-unir-vietnam-camboya-y.html)).

Does it still exist? Is there any other ferry available?

Comment: Oooh nice one, I want to know the answer to this. I know of ferries from Vietnam to Cambodia, but not whether it's possible to get from either of those countries to Thailand on ferry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ferries between Koh Kong and Sihanoukville ended a few years ago, and the service seems unlikely to return. Between the paving of the southern road, the rise in fuel prices, and the fall in foreign tourism it is no longer economically feasible, and despite the election of the Shinawatra government, tensions between the two countries are high due to various border disputes.

There are fast boats up and down the Mekong. You could take one from Chau Doc to Phnom Penh, then another from Phnom Penh to Tonle Sap, then ground transportation from Tonle Sap to Siem Reap for connections into Thailand, but as far as I know traveling exclusively by water into Thailand from Cambodia or Vietnam via scheduled service is not possible.

Comment: +1. This was my impression too of what the state of services in now. I wanted to go from Phonm Penh to Siem Reap via boat (or the other way round) and I found the services were no longer running.